# .NET MAUI display a popup from a popup

Tags: c#, windows, maui

I'm trying to use the community toolkit to display a popup from another Popup. From what I can tell, popups can only be displayed from a Page (which you can't convert a Popup to as far as I can tell). Does anyone know of a way to display a Popup or modal dialog from a popup? If anyone has an alternative solution I'm open to any suggestions as well.

I've tried to create an explicit operator to convert a Popup to a Page for the ShowPopupAsync method but I don't fully understand what I'm doing and it doesn't work.

Comment: you can access the current page using `App.Current.MainPage` but I don't know how it will behave if you try to launch a 2nd popup.  And even it allows it, it seems like it would be a poor UX

Comment: Thank you for the reply. From what I've tried, if you launch two popups from the main page then the second popup will only be displayed once the first popup is dismissed.

Comment: It might be helpful to add to question the code you tried (that does not work). Looking at Community Toolkit source code, I think you are correct: A popup is not a ContentPage, so cannot display a second popup, that would return to it afterwards. Consider using [RgPopup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup), in which `PopupPage` DOES inherit from `ContentPage`. That *might* make it possible to do what you want .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching I have found an answer that doesn't involve the community toolkit. Mopups (a spiritual successor of RgPopup) allows you to display a popup from another popup.
https://github.com/LuckyDucko/Mopups

I found out about Mopups from Gerald Versluis's Youtube channel. Here's his video on Mopups: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGWhgASmSto&ab_channel=GeraldVersluis

.xaml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mopups:PopupPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mopups="clr-namespace:Mopups.Pages;assembly=Mopups"
             x:Class="mopupsTest.MopupPopup1"
             Title="MopupPopup1"
                  BackgroundColor="#80000000">
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label 
            Text="This Is A Popup Page"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Open New Popup"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</mopups:PopupPage>
```

xaml.cs file:

```
    using Mopups.Services;

namespace mopupsTest;

public partial class MopupPopup1
{
    public MopupPopup1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MopupService.Instance.PushAsync(new MopupPopup2());
    }
}
```

With the code above I'm able to launch a second popup page (MopupPopup2) from my first popup page (MopupPopup1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) to simulate the first popup and add another popup on the first one.

Please refer to the following code:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  //pop up the first Popup
    var popup = new SimplePopup();

    this.ShowPopup(popup);
}
```

**SimplePopup.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class SimplePopup : Popup 
{
      public SimplePopup()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

 // pop up the second one   
      private async  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        string text = "This is a Toast";
        ToastDuration duration = ToastDuration.Short;
        double fontSize = 14;

        var toast = Toast.Make(text, duration, fontSize);

        await toast.Show(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
```

**SimplePopup.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiPickerApp1121.SimplePopup"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
            >
    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="10">
        <Label Text="This is a test message!" />

        <Button  Text="inner pop up"  Clicked="Button_Clicked"  Margin="20"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>
```